# make buyer direct pay to vender

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am using the module for multi vendor support

https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Extensions/Marketplace/Magento-Marketplace.html

In this the flow of payment is like, buyer pay and get transfer to owner account, than owner pay to the vendor. This is usual flow.

But I want the payment to get directly transfered to the vendor account without intermediate owner account, Can I do that? Help me to get solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use extension called adaptive payment.This will divide the money to multiple vendors at the time when checkout process redirect to paypal.There is a place for peecent commission in the module you mentioned above.This adaptive payment also seperate the commission. I am also currently using it.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

we are the developers of the magento marketplace module , for that purpose you can use marketplace paypal adaptive module , also marketplace module support for paypal marketplace api , stripe marketplace api , mangopay marketplace api , braintree marketplace api, wepay marketplace api and balanced marketplace api 
please find links here

https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace-Paypal-Adaptive-Payment.html
https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace-WePay-Payment-Gateway.html
https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace-MangoPay-Payment-Gateway.html
https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace-Stripe-Payment-Gateway.html

PS - i am not promoting products / links here just providing correct information as we are the developer of the module .